# Facebook - Canvas HTTPS Security Migration

Tags: php, facebook

I can't seem to find anything definitive, with the HTTPS migration, what will happen to existing apps that are just on HTTP? Will they cease to work? Or is it just a case that any new apps will need to be on HTTPS and the old ones will be fine?

If I read rightly I think it's a case that all existing apps will need to be converted.

Cheers guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, any existing apps that haven't entered a secure url will be disabled. My guess is they'll be stuck in sandbox mode until you enter that url.

Answer (score 1):

I just set up a test app today that embeds into the canvas. I found that while it requires it to be HTTPS, it doesn't care if you use a self-signed certificate, so they're not insisting that users spend money to keep using their canvas apps.